# Overwriting problem in localstorage angular

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have a problem with my project, I am trying to add different recipes in localStorage when I press an Add to favourite button, but if I click on 3 different recipes, they overwrite in localStorage instead of adding each one of them. I would like some help here if someone can have a little bit of time. Thank you so much

recipe.ts. - I have here the recipes from my backend, I fetch them and try to add them in localStorage

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataFromApi();
  }

  getDataFromApi() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('Response from API is', response);
        this.data = response;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Error is', error);
      }
    );
  }

add(i: any) {
    localStorage.setItem('Recipe', JSON.stringify(this.data[i]));
    console.log('Added in localstorage' + i);

    if (localStorage.getItem('Recipe') === null) {
      alert('TEST');
    }
  }

  remove() {
    localStorage.removeItem('Recipe');
    console.log('I deleted from localStorage');
  }
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let recipe of data; let i = index">
      <p>
        {{ recipe.title }}
      </p>
      <img src="{{ recipe.image }}" alt="" />
      <p>{{ recipe.description }}</p>
      <p>{{ recipe.calories }}</p>
      <p>{{ recipe.cookingTime }}</p>
      <p>{{ recipe._id }}</p>
      <button (click)="add(i)">Add to favorite</button>
      <button (click)="remove()">Remove from favorite</button>
    </div>
```

Right now if I press on Add to favourite I can see the recipe in localStorage but if I press on another Add to fav, the recipe that existed is overwritten with the new one. How can I solve to have them all in localStorage without overwriting? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per current implementation it will always override the `localStorage` value with latest one, normally `localStorage` store any data with a `key` & `value`, in your case whenever you are trying to `add to fav` you always passing one `key`, so that's why it override with latest one.

I have modified your code, please have a look, Hope it will help you

**ADD METHOD**

```
add(i: any) {
  let recipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Recipe")) || [];
  recipes.push(this.data[i]); 
  localStorage.setItem('Recipe', JSON.stringify(recipes));
  console.log('Added in localstorage' + i);

  if (localStorage.getItem('Recipe') === null) {
    alert('TEST');
  }
}
```

Might be possible you may facing issue with `remove item`, please have look to

**HTML CODE**

```
<div *ngFor="let recipe of data; let i = index">
  <p>
    {{ recipe.title }}
  </p>
  <img src="{{ recipe.image }}" alt="" />
  <p>{{ recipe.description }}</p>
  <p>{{ recipe.calories }}</p>
  <p>{{ recipe.cookingTime }}</p>
  <p>{{ recipe._id }}</p>
  <button (click)="add(i)">Add to favorite</button>
  <!-- pass this  recipe object with remove method -->
  <button (click)="remove(recipe)">Remove from favorite</button>
  
</div>
```

**REMOVE METHOD**

```
remove(recipe) {
  let recipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Recipe")) || [];
  if(recipes.length){
    recipes = recipes.filter((x:any) => x._id !== recipe._id); // this will remove the item from list
    localStorage.setItem('Recipe', JSON.stringify(recipes));
    console.log('I deleted from localStorage');
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Suneel Kumar, thanks for your answer, I really appreciate your time.  I face an issue regarding the remove method, its saying : Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type and can't make the app working again. Do you have any thoughts how can I solve this? Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @tirbushonn23, I have update my answer again, please have a look, & also it's just a minor change just need to change this `.filter(x => .....` to `.filter((x: any) => .....`

Comment: Hi Suneel, its working perfectly. Thank you so so much for everything. Have a lovely day.

Answer (score 1):

localStorage is just a simple key value store, each time you call `localStorage.setItem('Recipe', ...)` a new value is assigned to the key "Recipe" similar to a variable assignment.
If you want to store multiple Recipes in localStorage you can store all values as an array instead and each time you add a new value you fetch your previously stored values and push your new recipe in that array. Here is a possible solution

```
const recipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Recipes")) || [];
recipes.push(this.data[i]);
localStorage.setItem("Recipes", JSON.stringify(recipes));
```

If you want to store a bunch of data locally in a more robust way I can also recommend the use of IndexedDB: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API and/or a library which handles locally stored data such as https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb

Comment: Hi @west efan , thanks for your time, your solution its working , thank you so so much. Now I can see. different recipes in localStorage but do you have any idea how can I remove the one that I want from localStorage? If I use removeItem, I delete all of them at one. If you have any idea how can I delete the one that I want I would really appreciate. Thanks again for your time and your help.

Comment: Once you have the array you can use that array to handle your data, what you are looking for in this case is the splice functionality: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice